# Using profile on PowerShell not on ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am basically trying to customize my PowerShell a bit using a profile. I'm following some instructions from Internet, but the configuration works on the ISE but not on PowerShell itself. I'm using the profiles `$PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts`.

Here are some sceenshots:

Works on ISE:

[image: Works on ISE]

but not on PowerShell

[image]

Comment: i'm using the `$profile` variable. like so: `notepad $profile`. edit it, save it, reload powershell. but you need to do that from the ps session, not ise

Comment: Does `cat $profile.AllUsersAllHosts` in the PowerShell console show you the correct content? Do you have something in one of the other profiles that would override your settings? [Related](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers at the end it was my $PROFILE.AllUsersCurrentHost that was overriding everything I have in the $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHost. I just deleted the first one and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is in my ISE profile (I use my ISE as my master).

```
cp -Force "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1" "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"
```

Basically it writes whatever is in my ISE profile to my normal powershell profile everytime I start up ISE.

Depending on whether you are using ISE or plain Powershell `$profile` is a different value

**Plain PowerShell**

`$profile` = `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

**ISE**

`$profile` = `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`

You could theoretically change the value of `$profile` in one so that it uses the other :)